# Google Analytics API DataQuery object

Tags: java, eclipse, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to Java and to the Google Analytics API. I am using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1. I want to write a small console program in java that will read the output from another program(Start Date and End Date) from a console and query Google Analytics to return some Event Labels and write them to a csv.

I am having trouble getting started though. Google's getting started tutorial is not that helpful and also I can't figure out how to add jars from the API to my solution. I'm trying to use a DataQuery object because that is how the tutorial suggests you start, but I am pretty sure the object is not in any of the jar files that come with the Google Analytics API.

I think they are in the Core Reporting API. I installed the Google API plugin for eclipse but the Core Reporting API is not listed and I cannot find a download for it online.

Does anyone know how to download the Core Reporting API or if this is even the correct place to start?

Does anyone have any good examples of a Java program that does something similar that they are willing to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial of google having full java example you can customize it for different data queries
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataJava

This is query explorer tool provided by google

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/